# Reader only select empty Fields from MySQL-Database - Error Message: The Value cannot be NULL Paramter: Item

Tags: mysql, nullpointerexception, c++-cli, database-connection

If I try to select the Database from a MySQL Database I get a Error Message: The Value can not be NULL. Paramter: item (In German its: Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein. Parameter: item) So that means the Reader only select empty fields - he "selects NULL" - but the fields arent empty in my SQL-Database.

```
private: void Fillcombo(void) {

String^ constring = L"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=ichstinkenachmaggie";
MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand("select rank from database.ranks;", conDataBase);
MySqlDataReader^ myReader;

try {

    conDataBase->Open();
    myReader = cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader->Read()) {
        String^ vRank;
        myReader->GetString("rank");
        rank_combo->Items->Add(vRank);

    }

    }
catch (Exception^ex) {

    MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);

}

}
```

If replace the line:

```
rank_combo->Items->Add(vRank);
```

with this:

```
rank_combo->Items->Add(vRank + "*****");
```

then I dont get the error but in the combobox there are only 4 lines with 5 ***** :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialized the variable `vRank` to anything, of course it's still null. Did you forget to assign the result of `GetString` to `vRank`?

```
while (myReader->Read()) {
    String^ vRank;
    vRank = myReader->GetString("rank");
    ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: How did I not see this - ok this is really dumb and awkward from me its like so simple and Im sitting in front of the code and think that my MySQL is brocken and then its so simple - Thanks for your help :D